# How to add a hover effect to a GtkTreeView cell

Tags: c, gtk3

I have a `GtkTreeView` with two columns of type text (e.g. `G_TYPE_STRING`) and I am using `GtkCellRendererText` to render the column.

Is there any why that I can react when the mouse enters and leaves a certain cell and then hover or highlight the cell.

For example I would like to underline the text in the cell renderer, when the mouse enters it, in order to give a visual clue that the cell can be clicked to perform an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish the task. A few examples follow, separated by horizontal lines.

---

The simplest, and in some ways the best, option is to simply change the mouse cursor to a finger (same as the mouse cursor you see in a browser when pointing to a link) within the GtkTreeView.

Let's say `GtkTreeView *view` is the view we're interested in. **After** you have called `gtk_widget_show_all(window);`, you can call

```
GdkWindow  *win = gtk_tree_view_get_bin_window(GTK_TREE_VIEW(view));
GdkDisplay *disp = gdk_window_get_display(win);
gdk_window_set_cursor(win, gdk_cursor_new_from_name(disp, "pointer"));
```

With this, the mouse pointer will be a finger for all rows in the view, excluding the header row.

The set of cursor names you can use (instead of `"pointer"` above) is listed [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cursors.html#gdk-cursor-new-from-name) in the GDK3 documentation.

The downside is that if you have empty rows in the tree view, or separator rows, the mouse pointer will still look like a finger for those.

---

You can override the hover color by applying an application-specific CSS hover color, say

```
GtkTreeView:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

with e.g.

```
GtkCssProvider *css_provider;
css_provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
if (gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(css_provider, 
            "GtkTreeView:hover {\n"
            "    color: #ff0000;\n"
            "}\n"
            "", -1, NULL))
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(),
                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(css_provider),
                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
g_object_unref(css_provider);
```

after creating your main window. (Of course, you can include all application-specific CSS overrides in the CSS snippet.)

However, on gtk+ 3.18.9 at least, the renderer does not seem to support `text-decoration` or `font` CSS attributes here. (The GtkCssProvider does not seem to support `cursor` attribute at all, in case you're wondering.)

Also, since this essentially overrides the user theme, and there are a number of possible themes a Gtk+ user might be using, changing the color this way is unlikely to look good in all themes.

---

If your `GtkTreeView *view;` consists of clickable rows, and you don't need the selection for anything (that is, you don't have a separate button or something that causes an action to be applied to all the selected rows in the GtkTreeView), then you can simply set the selection to follow the mouse cursor:

```
gtk_tree_view_set_hover_selection(view, TRUE);
```

this causes the row you hover over to be selected, and therefore also highlighted.  You probably also want to limit the selection to one row at a time:

```
gtk_tree_selection_set_mode(gtk_tree_view_get_selection(view),
                            GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE);
```

---

As [Herbalist already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478627/1475978), you can create a custom GtkCellRendererText derivative, which changes the `PangoUnderline underline` property depending on whether the text cell being rendered is also prelit (hovered over) or not:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT           (custom_cell_renderer_text_get_type())
#define CUSTOM_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT(obj)           (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj), CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT, CustomCellRendererText))
#define CUSTOM_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT_CLASS(cls)     (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_CAST((cls),    CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT, CustomCellRendererTextClass))
#define CUSTOM_IS_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT(obj)        (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE((obj), CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT))
#define CUSTOM_IS_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT_CLASS(cls)  (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_TYPE((cls),    CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT))
#define CUSTOM_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT_GET_CLASS(obj) (G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_CLASS((obj),  CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT, CustomCellRendererTextClass))

GType  custom_cell_renderer_text_get_type(void) G_GNUC_CONST;

typedef struct {
    GtkCellRendererText  renderer;
} CustomCellRendererText;

typedef struct {
    GtkCellRendererTextClass  parent_class;
} CustomCellRendererTextClass;

G_DEFINE_TYPE(CustomCellRendererText, custom_cell_renderer_text, GTK_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT);

void custom_cell_renderer_text_render(GtkCellRenderer *cell,
                                      cairo_t *cr,
                                      GtkWidget *widget,
                                      const GdkRectangle *backarea,
                                      const GdkRectangle *cellarea,
                                      GtkCellRendererState state)
{
    if (state & GTK_CELL_RENDERER_PRELIT) {
        const PangoUnderline prelit = PANGO_UNDERLINE_SINGLE;
        PangoUnderline curr;
        g_object_get(cell, "underline", &curr, NULL);
        g_object_set(cell, "underline", prelit, NULL);
        ((GtkCellRendererClass *)custom_cell_renderer_text_parent_class)->render(cell, cr, widget, backarea, cellarea, state);
        g_object_set(cell, "underline", curr, NULL);
    } else
        ((GtkCellRendererClass *)custom_cell_renderer_text_parent_class)->render(cell, cr, widget, backarea, cellarea, state);
}

void custom_cell_renderer_text_class_init(CustomCellRendererTextClass *cls)
{
    ((GtkCellRendererClass *)cls)->render = custom_cell_renderer_text_render;
    return;
}

void custom_cell_renderer_text_init(CustomCellRendererText *renderer)
{
    return;
}

GtkCellRenderer *custom_cell_renderer_text_new(void)
{
    return g_object_new(CUSTOM_TYPE_CELL_RENDERER_TEXT, NULL);
}
```

If you then replace your `gtk_cell_render_text_new()` with `custom_cell_render_text_new()` (and change `GtkCellRenderText *` to `CustomCellRenderText *`) in your GtkTreeView code, the row you hover on in the GtkTreeView will become underlined.

Note that all cells in the row you hover over will be highlighted, not just the cell/column you hover over. This is because in a GtkTreeView, the row (or index) is the unit being manipulated (rather than a specific cell on a specific column).

If you use the above renderer only for some columns in your GtkTreeView, the text in those columns will get underlined even when the mouse hovers over some other column on that row.

Also note that if you don't want all rows to indicate clickability, you can add a third column in your data model -- name `"sensitive"`, type `G_TYPE_BOOLEAN` for gboolean type; value `TRUE` if the row is clickable, `FALSE` if the row is non-clickable -- and change the `if` clause in `custom_cell_renderer_text_render()` to

```
    const GtkStateFlags  flags = gtk_cell_renderer_get_state(cell, widget, state);
    if ((state & GTK_CELL_RENDERER_PRELIT) &&
       !(flags & GTK_STATE_FLAG_INSENSITIVE)) {
```

Gtk+ will render rows with `TRUE` normally, and rows with `FALSE` as separators or disabled text, because the column names in the model are automatically associated with the GtkCellRenderer properties of the same name.

Comment: @lanoxx: What was your intent with the nonfunctional edits to the example code? The code as shown is tested to work, and your changes provided no functional differences, so what was their purpose? (I found the edit attempt *suspicious*, to be honest, so I'd like some clarification here, please.)

Comment: Apologies for messing up the code listing. I was trying to reformat it to avoid having to scroll left and right. This would make the code listing much more readable in my opinion. The use of either `G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE` or `G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE` you also make the listing shorter, because you do not need to define those 6 macros at the top and depending on which of these two macros you use, you can omit some of the `struct` declarations.

Comment: Btw. I do not think this addition is necessary: **(and change GtkCellRenderText * to CustomCellRenderText *) in your GtkTreeView code,**, since the custom renderer's new function actually returns a `GtkCellRenderer` instance.

Comment: Based on your code here is a solution that uses `G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE`: https://gist.github.com/lanoxx/10929bca7a0d34b5cb2552b2b6e74149

Comment: @lanoxx: You should add an answer with the code that solved your issue, then. If you used my example code as a basis for it, a reference -- link to, or mention of -- my answer is sufficient. (I am not here to gather "score", but to help others find robust and interesting solutions to interesting problems. As I mentioned above, I found your edit "suspicious" and rolled it back, because it provided no functional changes.) If you do supply your own answer/code, please do explain why you arrived and chose that particular one, so that others encountering the same problem get maximum information.

Comment: Maybe you can just re-format the code a little so that your code is readable without having to scroll to the right.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom CellRendererText and set the underline property if the PRELIT flag is present.

i only know in Python:

```
class My_CellRendererText( Gtk.CellRendererText ):
def __init__( self ):
    super().__init__()

def do_render( self, cr, widget, background_area, cell_area, flags ):
    self.props.underline = ( ( flags & Gtk.CellRendererState.PRELIT ) != 0 )
    return Gtk.CellRendererText.do_render( self, cr, widget, background_area, cell_area, flags )

GObject.type_register( My_CellRendererText )
```